# Issue with ArrayIndexOutOfRange

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

> I am trying to implement this pseudocode:
>
> ALGORITHM BruteForce (Weights [1 ... N], Values [1 ... N], A[1...N])
>   //Finds the best possible combination of items for the KP //Input:
>   Array Weights contains the weights of all items Array Values contains
>   the values of all items Array A initialized with 0s is used to
>   generate the bit strings //Output: Best possible combination of items
>   in the knapsack bestChoice [1 .. N]

```
for i = 1 to 2^n do 
    j = n
    tempWeight = 0 
    tempValue = 0
    while ( A[j] != 0 and j > 0)
        A[j] = 0
        j = j–1 
    A[j] = 1
    for k = 1 to n do
        if (A[k] = 1) then
            tempWeight = tempWeight + Weights[k]
            tempValue = tempValue + Values[k]
    if ((tempValue > bestValue) AND (tempWeight <= Capacity)) then
            bestValue = tempValue 
            bestWeight = tempWeight
            bestChoice = A 
return bestChoice
```

> Here is my try at it:

```
public class BruteForce {

    public static final int CAPACITY = 50;

    public static double[] bruteForce(double[] weights, double[] values, double[] A) {
        int n = weights.length;
        int j;
        double[] bestChoice = null;
        double tempWeight;
        double tempValue;
        double bestValue = 0;
        double bestWeight = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
            j = n;
            tempWeight = 0;
            tempValue = 0;
            // Here is the issue of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 3
            while (A[j] != 0 && j > 0) {
                A[j] = 0;
                j = j - 1;
            }
            A[j] = 1;
            for (int k = 1; k < n; k++) {
                if (A[k] == 1) {
                    tempWeight = tempWeight + weights[k];
                    tempValue = tempValue + values[k];
                }
            }
            if ((tempValue > bestValue) && (tempWeight <= CAPACITY)) {
                bestValue = tempValue;
                bestWeight = tempWeight;
            }
            bestChoice = A;
        }

        return bestChoice;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] weights = { 10, 20, 15 };
        double[] values = { 5, 10, 30 };
        double[] A = new double[weights.length];
        BruteForce.bruteForce(weights, values, A);

    }

}
```

> I keep on getting an ArrayIndex out of bounds. But I don't know why
>   `A`'s length is set to `weights` length so there shouldn't be any
>   error in my mind. What am I doing wrong? This is an algorithm for
>   solving the knapsack problem btw. Just in case anyone is familiar with
>   it and would offer any critiquing of this algorithm.
>
> EDIT: I've changed this:
>
> ```
>           while (A[j-1] != 0 && j > 0) {
>               A[j] = 0; // This would need to be changed too then right? 
>               j = j - 1;
>           }
>           A[j-1] = 1; // This changed
> ```

Comment: Look at the line `j = n;`. That's equivalent to `j = weights.length;` You then use `A[j]`, and `A` has the same length as `weights`. So that will *always* fail. Arrays are zero-indexed in Java.

Comment: you translated `2n` to `Math.pow(2,n)` meaning 2^n. Is that what the algorithm meant ?

Comment: Yes. When I copied over the pseudocode, it eliminated the ^. I have updated the question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You misunderstood Jon Skeet's point. You should jave `int j = n - 1;` to avoid the ArrayOutOfBoundException. EDIT : It's rather the translation from the [1..N] in pseudocode to [0..n[ that breaks.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I wasn't very clear but, as Jon said : in java, the index of an Array goes from 0 to length-1. Thus, you should start your counters from 0 (otherwise, you'll miss the first item) and stop before reaching n.

Comment: Yup, I changed that as well. The only part I seem to be missing is how does `bestChoice` array get populated? It is just assigned to `A`. and `A` is filled with all 0's except the last index has a 1 so that is the stopping point. So my output would be `[0,0,1]`. But I of course want the `bestChoices` to be populated by the `bestWeights`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `j = 3`
Arrays positions start at `0`

```
A[0]
A[1]
A[2]
```

You need a `-1`

Comment: So I can't start from the end of the array is what you're saying? I have to iterate from the beginning to end?

Comment: No, you just have to do j = n - 1

Comment: Do you mind checking out my edit to see if I implemented it correctly?